# How to get matched route in context in Gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have this code :

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.New()
    r.GET("/user/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // How can I get the litteral string "/user/:id" here ?
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"message": "received request"})
    })
}
```

Is there any way that I can retrieve inside the handler the litteral string `/user/:id`? If I use `c.Request.Path` it will give me the full output of the path like `/user/10`.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it, why you need that string?

Comment: There is no way, you would need to make some magic stuff, for example save all routes on a map, and compare that map with the current URL (you would need to replace params with their route value tho)

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation you can use [FullPath()](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.FullPath).

```golang
router.GET("/user/:id", func(c *gin.Context) {
    c.FullPath() == "/user/:id" // true
})
```

Comment: (Hi - There was no need to delete your last post; I just wanted to point out that other methods were available)

Comment: Gave what I expected. 100% Correct.